# Count rows with same dates

Tags: r

I have the following variable:

```
     datevote 
1   1981-6-21
2   1981-6-21
3   1981-9-23
4   1982-2-14
5   1982-2-14
```

and so on...

What I'd like to have in the end is a new column in which the number of the same dates of column "datevote" ist displayed:

```
  datevote        numbervotes
1   1981-6-21     2
2   1981-6-21     2
3   1981-9-23     1
4   1982-2-14     2
5   1982-2-14     2
```

I have tried several things, but it seems more work than expected. Can anyone help me?
All the help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: I guess `?ave` could be helpful. `ave(DF$datevote, DF$datevote, FUN = length)`, or something similar depending on the output of `str(DF)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the new `dplyr` package like this.

```
library(dplyr)
df <- data.frame(datevote = as.Date(c("1981-06-21", "1981-06-21", "1981-06-23", "1981-06-14", "1981-06-14")))

mutate(group_by(df, datevote), numbervotes = n(datevote))
##     datevote numbervotes
## 1 1981-06-21           2
## 2 1981-06-21           2
## 3 1981-06-23           1
## 4 1981-06-14           2
## 5 1981-06-14           2
```

The equivalent `plyr` solution is :

```
detach(package:dplyr)
library(plyr)
ddply(df, "datevote", mutate, numbervotes = length(datevote))
```

Comment: Thank you for your input. Unfortunately it does not work. R gives me an `Error in nchar(values) : invalid multibyte string 265`

Comment: @Thomas Make sure to have the latest CRAN version of `dplyr`. I also want to know when you copy and paste the code as is does it work ?

Comment: When I copy and paste your code R gives me this: Error in n(datevote) : unused argument (datevote).

Comment: @Thomas devtools::install_github("dplyr") and try again. If you still have some issue then use the `plyr` solution

Answer (score 3):

Data.table alternative:

```
df <- data.frame(datevote = as.Date(c("1981-06-21", "1981-06-21", "1981-06-23", "1981-06-14", "1981-06-14")))
library(data.table)
df <- data.table(df)
df[,numbervotes:=.N, by=datevote]
df
```